# Apply function on the rows of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

Let's say I have a 5 by 7 matrix and a function `f` :

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(7*5),5,7)
f <- function(x,y) sum(x+y)
```

I would like to compute the matrix b whose element `b[i,j]` is equal to  `f(a[i,],a[j,])` without for loops. How could I do ?

Comment: `f` will return a vector, not a single value. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: I have given a bad example... Sorry. I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `outer` to apply a function to all possible combinations:

```
rowNums <- seq(nrow(a)) # vector with all row numbers

outer(rowNums, rowNums, Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(a[x, ] + a[y, ])))

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,]  6.319860 10.978305  6.911812  2.4609471 4.7021136
[2,] 10.978305 15.636751 11.570257  7.1193924 9.3605589
[3,]  6.911812 11.570257  7.503764  3.0528993 5.2940659
[4,]  2.460947  7.119392  3.052899 -1.3979658 0.8432008
[5,]  4.702114  9.360559  5.294066  0.8432008 3.0843673
```

---

*Edit*:

The calculations are more efficient if you calculate the `rowSums` before using `outer`. This code is shorter and faster:

```
rs <- rowSums(a)

outer(rs, rs, "+")

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,]  6.319860 10.978305  6.911812  2.4609471 4.7021136
[2,] 10.978305 15.636751 11.570257  7.1193924 9.3605589
[3,]  6.911812 11.570257  7.503764  3.0528993 5.2940659
[4,]  2.460947  7.119392  3.052899 -1.3979658 0.8432008
[5,]  4.702114  9.360559  5.294066  0.8432008 3.0843673
```

---

*Edit 2*:

A solution to your actual problem (see comments):

```
ta <- t(a) # transpose

apply(a, 1, function(x) colSums(abs(ta - x)))

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,]  0.000000 10.687579 10.933269 9.306339 7.763612
[2,] 10.687579  0.000000  7.465742 8.517358 7.847622
[3,] 10.933269  7.465742  0.000000 5.768676 6.851272
[4,]  9.306339  8.517358  5.768676 0.000000 6.687477
[5,]  7.763612  7.847622  6.851272 6.687477 0.000000
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, it runs 4 times slower than the simple double for loop in my code...

Comment: @Pop I added a more efficient `outer` solution.

Comment: But the function I use is a bit more complex than sum : `f <- function(x,y) exp(-sum(abs(x-y)))`

Comment: In fact I'm looking for is a way to do this quicker : 
`b <- matrix(0,N,N);
  for (i in 1:N)
    for (j in 1:N)
      b[i,j] <- sum(abs(a[i,]-a[j,]))`
If it is exists...

Comment: @Pop A hint for the next time: Ask you *actual* question!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `expand.grid` to create to subsetting indicies and use on this `apply` on this:

```
matrix(apply(expand.grid(seq(nrow(a)),seq(nrow(a))),1,
  function(x) f(a[x[1],],a[x[2],])),nrow(a))
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 8.9116431  4.1067161  0.6589584  3.681561  3.207056
[2,] 4.1067161 -0.6982109 -4.1459686 -1.123366 -1.597871
[3,] 0.6589584 -4.1459686 -7.5937263 -4.571123 -5.045629
[4,] 3.6815615 -1.1233656 -4.5711232 -1.548520 -2.023026
[5,] 3.2070558 -1.5978712 -5.0456289 -2.023026 -2.497531
```

Comment: As I will use matrices with big number of rows, I think I should avoid `expand.grid`. But thanks for the answer ;)